# Modifying parent constructor function does not effect child

Tags: javascript

When modifying constructor function definition after it was already used to create an object, do the object properties get overwritten as if the object was recreated on its own? Similar to how prototype chain keeps methods updated when prototype gets modified.

```
function ParentFunction(a){
this.a = a;
this.method = function(){console.log(this.name);}
}

var parent = {};
parent.__proto__ = ParentFunction.prototype;
ParentFunction.call(parent,1);

//child linking
var child = {};
child.__proto__ = parent; // child now has a and method


// changing parent constructor
parent.__proto__.constructor = function ParentFunction(a){
this.a = a;
this.method = function(){console.log("new");}
}

// this does not change child.method function. why not?
```

Comment: no, you can only change own props on a per-object basis.

Comment: Assigning `ParentFunction.prototype.constructor` (or `Object.getPrototypeOf(parent).constructor`, it's the same thing) does not affect anything. You need to *call* your new constructor function on the instance to make it initialise the new property values.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use **proto** as it's deprecated, use prototype in conjunction with Object.create e.g:

   ```
   SomeClass.prototype = Object.create(SomeOtherClass.prototype);
   ```
2. Don't put methods inside of your constructor. By doing so, that method will be created for each instance. Put that method on a prototype so members can share it e.g.

   ```
   SomeClass.prototype.someMethod = () => {...}
   ```

When it comes to your question, it has been answered in one of the comments already.

Comment: that's a bit broad, you definitely want own methods in some circumstances, security by closure for example...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a method for all instances of a type then don't attach the method to the instance of the object with the constructor function, attach it to the prototype.

```js
function Obj() {
  this.x = 5;
}

Obj.prototype.method = function () {
  console.log(`Original method displays the value of x: ${this.x}`);
}

let instance = new Obj();

instance.method();

Obj.prototype.method = function () {
  console.log(`New method displays the value of x times 2: ${this.x * 2}`);
}

instance.method();
```